# SQL Server memory support

Tags: sql-server

I made the database in  SQL Server. My database is added by automatic trigger (about 0.5s/time). so its memory increases very fast.

I want to remove old database by query in sql server. How can I do that?

Comment: you want delete a database by tsql query?

Comment: that's right. Is that impossible?
Futhermore, I want to delete n ending rows but SQL doesnt any query what cans make that directtly.